# Inversion rule in conditional sentence type 1

Tags: inversion

As you know, we can use inversion rule in  conditional sentence type 1: for instance:

> If you should need something, please call me.
>   → Should you need something, please call me.

Now, can I apply this rule to the following sentence?

> If there is any question, please do not hesitate to contact me.
>   → Is there any question, please do not hesitate to contact me.

Comment: No: in certain conditionals the protasis (the _if_ bit), can have the form of a content clause with subject-auxiliary inversion instead of the usual preposition phrase 'if + content clause complement'. But "is there any question" is not a content clause -- not even a subordinate clause -- and hence the whole sentence is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1):

No, in order to invert the condition in

> If there are any questions, please do not hesitate to contact me

you would need to change it to

> Should there be any questions, please do not hestiate to contact me.

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific, the reason that the first sentence is inverted in that way is that the first verb is in the subjunctive. This can also be done with the verb "is" in the second sentence, yielding *Be there any question...*, but this is extremely archaic. In short, the inverted form **requires** the subjunctive but the in the non-inverted form it is optional. This along with the fact that the subjunctive form of *to be* is extremely archaic sounding means that to invert the second sentence, modern English speakers would either (a) change the verb as in @rjpond's answer or (b) just decide against inverting it and leave it as it is.